# Can`t run google maps apiv2 in android unfurto

Tags: android

Hello i am traying to follow this tutorial

http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/google-maps-api-v2-android-tutorial/
and i downloaded the source code but i cant get it run

this my debug logcat when i run the applicatino on the adv

```
       01-07 19:12:44.086: I/dalvikvm(630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
       01-07 19:12:44.106: I/dalvikvm(630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
       01-07 19:12:51.036: I/Process(630): Sending signal. PID: 630 SIG: 9
       01-07 19:15:28.196: I/dalvikvm(678): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
       01-07 19:15:28.296: I/dalvikvm(678): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
       01-07 19:15:28.466: D/AndroidRuntime(678): Shutting down VM
       01-07 19:15:28.466: W/dalvikvm(678): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapsv2/com.example.mapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.example.mapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   ... 11 more
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
       01-07 19:15:28.486: E/AndroidRuntime(678):   ... 20 more
       01-07 19:15:28.706: I/dalvikvm(678): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
       01-07 19:15:28.726: I/dalvikvm(678): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
       01-07 19:15:29.106: I/dalvikvm(678): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
       01-07 19:15:29.126: I/dalvikvm(678): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
       01-07 19:15:36.495: I/Process(678): Sending signal. PID: 678 SIG: 9
```

and the xml code is here

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.mapsv2"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCyR3kVxyrriZlavRfsly-lBYo8Pl4VMkM" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapsv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good habit to read error message first:

> E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the
>   right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the
>   following declaration within the  element:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

so add this to your manifest.